# Bounds on twin prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, asymptotics, twin-primes

I read somewhere (unfortunately I cannot find the paper again) that the twin prime counting function $\pi_2(x)$ satisfies $\pi_2(x) \leq C\frac{x}{\log^2x}$ for some constant $C$. How would one prove (or disprove) this? I can see how one would determine it heuristically with the prime number theorem but I want something more rigorous. If the formula is true, are there any bounds on $C$? Furthermore, is there an analogous formula for the number of primes $p$ such that $p + k$ is also prime, for a fixed positive integer $k$?

Comment: Yes, this can be done by a standard application of the Selberg sieve.  Maybe you'll find this expository [blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/254a-notes-4-some-sieve-theory/) of Tao helpful.  It's easy to see the same method of proof will also work for any fixed $k$.  But the constant $C$ depends on $k$, being larger when $k$ has a lot of small prime divisors (and I believe it should grow arbitrarily large).

Comment: @Erick Wong are the upper bounds proven, or only conjectured ?

Comment: @Peter The upper bounds are proven, hence my use of the term "method of proof".  It's the lower bounds that are always hard to establish (more precisely, a lower bound that is stronger than the trivial lower bound of $0$).